# XSLT otherwise block does not execute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XML

```
<Categories>
  <category>
    <blog>ABC</blog>
    <link>open</link>
    <link1>close</link1>
  </category>
</Categories>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="category">

  <xsl:variable name="openCloseValidation">
     <xsl:value-of select="link" />

  </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="holidayValidation">
     <xsl:value-of select="link1" />

  </xsl:variable>

    <h1><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($openCloseValidation)" /></h1>
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($holidayValidation)" /></h1>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($openCloseValidation, 'open')">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($holidayValidation, 'close'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
      </xsl:otherwise>

  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the first condition does not satisfy but it doesn't go in to otherwise block and display false.

Can you let me know if something is wrong here?

Comment: Your input accept the `when` block, but not the `if` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `xsl:when` condition is satisfied, as `contains($openCloseValidation, 'open')` is true. But within your `xsl:when` you have an `xsl:if` and if that fails, then nothing will get output.

You should rewrite it as this....

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($openCloseValidation, 'open') and not(contains($holidayValidation, 'close'))">
      <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

As an aside, it is much better to write your variable declarations like so...

```
<xsl:variable name="openCloseValidation" select="link" />
```

Comment: And another bit of coding advice: I suspect you're using `contains(node, 'value')` where you should be using `node='value'`. The `contains()` match succeeds not only on "open" but also on "openly" or "pseudopendant".